# How to handle close event of the window in Swift on Mac Catalyst?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, mac-catalyst

There is no NSWindow in Mac Catalyst, there is only UIWindow available.
I tried to use applicationWillTerminate.

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

However it's too late because the window is closed already.

Comment: Try `applicationWillResignActive`

Comment: applicationWillResignActive is different from window close event.

Answer (score 2):

If you implement a scene delegate you should be able to use the sceneDidDisconnect method.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowscenedelegate

Answer (score 0):

In your viewController you can add the follow. When you close the window that contains this view or viewController you can handle all your task and exit the app

```
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("The window is gone")
        exit(0)
    }
```